# Wordpress DB two value in one column and AND with other column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

What is the correct syntax of this? I know this was wrong because I called but I need something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = 'request_count' AND (`meta_key` = 'approval' AND `meta_value` = '1');
```

I tried this one

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` IN ('request_count','approval') AND `meta_value` = '1';
```

But it doesnt do what I want to do.

**EDIT**

```
ID |Meta_key       | Meta_value|
1  |request_count  | 1         |
1  |approval       | 1         |
2  |approval       | 1         |
3  |request_count  | 2         |
3  |approval       | 2         |
```

I want to display the ID 1 because it has a **request_count** in *meta_key* and its **approval** in *meta_key* is **equal** to **1**

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you want it to do?  Show table and expected output please.

Comment: @Bleach done edit my question sir

Comment: ID field is post_id, correct?

Comment: @SamiulAminShanto yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your example data, following query should work:

```
SELECT pm.*, (select pm2.value FROM wp_postmeta pm2 WHERE pm2.post_id = pm.post_id AND pm2.`key` = 'approval' AND pm2.`value` = '1') AS approval 
FROM wp_postmeta pm
WHERE pm.`key` = 'request_count'
HAVING approval = 1
```

Even this query will work, I believe data structure is not correct. BTW, that is another issue.

Comment: yes the data structure is not correct it was wordpress given DB

Comment: Unknown column 'pm2' in 'field list'

I got this error

Comment: Got it uyuan thanks for this I just need it to modify a little bit. But I get the logic behind this.